# Launching a asp.net core app using VS2017 creates new Application Pool

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, application-pool

Each time when I launch the debugger for an ASP.net core application under local IIS from VS2017, a new Application pool is created.

I wish the application to remain stable under the DefaultAppPool 'Identity', and not create a new one.

Where is this setting to influence this?

I can manually set it to the old value using IIS management console, but it's getting tiresome.

[image: Showing the newly created app pool]

Comment: Hi! Did you have any outcome here? I got the same issue and this is the first hit :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are experiencing is most likely a side effect of the new InProcess hosting model that was introduced with .NET Core 2.2. Check your .csproj file for this line:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

InProcess hosting allows only one IIS site per application pool. It will generate new app pools on the fly if this condition is not met.

You can return to the old Kestrel hosting by removing the above line or by changing it to:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

The difference between In- and OutOfProcess hosting is also reflected in web.config, so you may have to change it there too if you want to go back. Look for the aspNetCore node in system.webServer:

```
        <aspNetCore 
            processPath="..." 
            arguments="..." 
            stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
            stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
            hostingModel="InProcess"
        >
```

Again, you may remove the hostingModel entry or change its value to "OutOfProcess" :

```
        <aspNetCore 
            ...
            hostingModel="OutOfProcess"
        >
```

**But wait!**

You may actually want to reconsider and adopt the new InProcess model for reasons explained in the following.

**New InProcess hosting vs. old Kestrel hosting**

Before .NET Core 2.2 all Core web applications on IIS were run using a second web server called **Kestrel**. Kestrel is lightweight and fast but lacks many functions of a full-blown web server. So IIS was used as a proxy in front of Kestrel to add all higher functionality (like redirects, authentication etc.). As you may imagine, cascading two web servers will reduce overall performance and consumes additional resources.

Since .NET Core 2.2 there is another option: **InProcess hosting**
If you activate InProcess hosting, IIS uses an in-process server implementation for IIS called IISHttpServer. This implementation as well as the Core app itself run in the same process as the IIS worker process. This reduces the resource footprint and increases performance.
There is one limitation though: Each InProcess hosting site in ISS needs a dedicated application pool. You cannot use the same application pool for multiple sites that are configured for InProcess hosting!
Also remember that this unique app pool requires read and write access to the site's folder or any other folders where the app reads and writes files. Otherwise you will get 503 errors.

**Basic InProcess configuration**

A typical PropertyGroup entry in .csproj for an InProcess project looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can easily switch back and forth between new InProcess and old Kestrel hosting by simply changing `InProcess` to `OutOfProcess` and vice versa.

**More info**

For more information on InProcess hosting see: [ASP.NET Core Hosting Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0#hosting-models)
For info on migrating existing Core projects to InProcess hosting see: [Adopt the IIS in-process hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#adopt-the-iis-in-process-hosting-model)

Comment: This answer helped me get to the solution. Everything worked fine when pointing at a root iis site. But when pointing my project at a sub application, which is created using the parents app pool, VS would attempt to create a new App pool and failed each time. Changing the app pool to the sub app to a new one AND restarting IIS AND Visual Studio resolved my issue!